# How to POST - API in thingspeak.comusing urllib in Python

Tags: python, api, post, urllib

I am working on a project where I have to get data from a website and then post it to a different website. At the moment I am still new, so I am using a thingspeak.com account to experiment on posting, and I am also following the same example used in the documentations of urllib, https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html.

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
# I am using this to check => eggs=2&bacon=0&spam=1
print params 
f = urllib.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?key=8TU6AC31T81MV52N&field1=",params)
print f.read()
```

However, when I check my thingspeak website http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/42628/feed.json?key=8TU6AC31T81MV52N, I will get this for that specific entry

```
{"created_at":"2015-06-17T10:05:12Z","entry_id":19,"field1":""}
```

Supposedly, or at least how I understood it, params should be posted to the website but I don't understand why I get the empty string. Also, it doesn't  work if I loop it, it only works for the first iteration posting the empty string, and the rest are I will get 0 read from f.read(). What's the problem?! :\

All help is much appreciated. Also please correct if by I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending the query parameter named `field1` in the URL, but it is set to any empty string. Hence `field1` is set to `""` by thingspeak.com. Those values you pass in `params` are sent in the *body* of the HTTP POST request, they are not somehow appended to the URL.

You can set the field in one of two ways:

- a GET request using:

  ```
  f = urllib.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?key=8TU6AC31T81MV52N&field1=my+value")
  ```

  which includes the API key and a value for `field1`.
- a POST request:

  ```
  params = urllib.urlencode({'key': '8TU6AC31T81MV52N', 'field1': 'my value'})
  f = urllib.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update", data=params)
  ```

thinkspeak will accept query parameters in the URL with a POST request, e.g. you can pass `field1` in the URL and the API key in the body:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'key': '8TU6AC31T81MV52N'})
f = urllib.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?field1=hello", data=params)
```

However, playing around with the API it looks like it will only accept the query parameter named `field1`. All other fields are ignored, even those [documented](https://thingspeak.com/docs/channels#update_feed) such as `field2`, `field3`, etc.

Comment: Ahmed, you might also like to check out http://httpbin.org which allows you to experiment with HTTP POST requests and simply responds with a JSON encoded version of your POST request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help sir. Atm the moment I want to try httpbin.org, but I am still not sure how to use curl but anyways, I just tried and it worked with this code : `params = urllib.urlencode({'key': '8TU6AC31T81MV52N', 'field1': {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0}})
 
 f = urllib.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update", data=params)` and it worked :D! But I am still facing the looping problem. If I try to post every a few seconds for example, it will just read the first reading, and the rest will be like ignored! Is it from thingspeak or there's something that I need to fix?

Comment: Updates to each channel are rate limited to 1 every 15 seconds - see https://thingspeak.com/docs/channels#rate_limits